# Netlogo: How to delete the "go" results keeping the "setup" ones?

Tags: installation, netlogo

Is it possible, in Netlogo, to delete (clear) the results gotten after the "go or start" procedure keeping the setup unvaried.
I want to do 2 different simulation keeping unvaried the initial conditions of the world.

Thank you

Comment: Just running setup again will restart the model so it's not clear what you're asking. Have you looked at BehaviorSpace to manage multiple simulations?

Comment: My setup procedure produces random numbers. I want to run multiple scenarios (GO procedure) taking fixed initial random numbers. Summaring, I want that every time I click SETUP I get the same world.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive you want is `random-seed`. If you set the seed, the same world will be created each time (and the same simulation will occur if you don't change the parameters)

Comment: And if after `setup` if you want each run to be different from that point forward, do `random-seed new-seed` after `setup` but before `go`.